# Mathematical defintion of a standing wave?

Tags: waves

I know that a standing wave is the superposition of two waves of equal amplitude and wavelength, moving in opposite directions. But I am looking for a more mathematical defintion of such a wave. The best I can come up with is that (I am foucsing on 1d) its displacement can be written as:
$$y=f(x)g(t)$$
But I am not sure if this is right? If not can you please provide me with a mathematical defintion (along with a source if possible) thanks.

Comment: What about your first sentence is not mathematical? You can write down the formula for a wave, and then write down the general formula for a standing wave, can you not?

Comment: @ACuriousMind It doesn't seem general enough, and ristricted to a special case. I wouln't know how to formulate it mathematically in the general case (e.g. with non-harmonic waves)

Comment: I do not believe there is a treatment of this for the general anharmonic case.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Ok assuming that my first statment can be put into mathetmacial terms. Even so can we say a stationary wave is a wave that satifies the equation I have given?

Comment: Your formula does not work, because the travelling wave $e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$ can be written as a product of your form---$e^{ikx}e^{-i\omega t}$

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs Good point!  Perhaps Joseph's definition would work if $f$ and $g$ are required to be real (or if $fg$ must be real).  Technically, only the real part of your wave describes the displacement, and it cannot be written in Joseph's form.

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs This is simply not true : a propagating wave will always be described by the **real part** of $e^{i(kx-\omega t)}$ i.e. $\cos(kx-\omega t)$. If you dont take the real part at the end, nothing that you state has any physical meaning. That exactly what pwf is stating : everything at the end must be real.

Comment: I guess I had a broader interpretation of what a wave was. I was thinking of something like a wavefunction where the phase is physically meaningful.